# Eloquent : condition based nested eager loading

Tags: laravel, nested, eager-loading, eloquent

I have 4 tables. **combos, products, product_variants, combo_product** (pivot table). **combo_product** has 2 columns viz **reference, reference_id**.

Now, I want to attach relationship condition based.

**if(reference == 'product')** then **with('products.product_details')** and

**if(reference == 'product_variant')** then **with('products.product_variant_details')**.

This are the relationships I have:

Combo.php

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\V1\Models\ComboProduct');
}
```

ComboProduct.php

```
public function product_details()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\V1\Models\Product', 'product_reference_id');
}
public function product_variant_details()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\V1\Models\ProductVariant', 'product_reference_id', 'product_variant_id');
}
```

I managed to get one relationship, but i can't get the other relationship condition based.
Here is my code.

```
Combo::whereComboId($id)->with([
   'products' => function ($query) {
        $query->with(['product_details'])
            ->where('product_reference', 'product'); 
         }
    ])->get();
```